# Distinct() strings from column of string[] array, how to get this with pure LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I could not find any similar example. In my DB I have a column of `string[]` array, where they are divided with comma. Example of 3 rows:

```
id1: apple, orange, banana, kiwi
id2: orange, kiwi
id3: lemon, pineaple, kiwi
```

From this list I need to extract with **LINQ** a List of distinct strings: `apple, orange, banana, kiwi, lemon, pineapple`.

I managed to do it, but not purely **LINQ**, but when using also `foreach`:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetFruitDetailedType()
        {
            List<string> all = new List<string>();
            var qry = await GetFruitsQueryable().Select(v => v.DetailedType).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var item in qry)
            {
                foreach(var type in item)
                {
                    all.Add(type);
                }
            }
            return (from w in all select w).Distinct().ToList();
        }
```

Is there a way to do it just with **LINQ**, without calling for object with all entities?

NOTE: using EF Core 2.

Comment: You're looking for `SelectMany` to flat map a list of lists.

Comment: @JonathonChase looks like you are right. Thank you. Is it more efficient than my approach? Do you have any idea maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the nested for loops is pretty straight-forward, as you're simply doing a flat mapping of a collection of collections. The LINQ extension you want for this is [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8). Using it, you could reduce your function to something like this:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetFruitDetailedType() 
{
    var qry = await GetFruitsQueryable().Select(v => v.DetailedType).ToListAsync();
    return qry.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

I haven't tested the following, but I also suspect it may work as well:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetFruitDetailedType()
{
    return await GetFruitsQueryable().SelectMany(x => x.DetailedType)
                                     .Distinct()
                                     .ToListAsync();
}
```